# JQuery Promise() behaving Unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, promise

I have HTML elements (lets call them "new_node", "new_transaction", and "new_modal") that I am creating dynamically. My method for creating these elements is appending raw HTML code that is common first in my inner-function, then I add in some JavaScript conditionals to build each element to what it specifically needs before I display that element on the page. In some cases, I only need to create only one "new_transaction", and in other cases I will need to create a "new_node" then several "new_transaction" child elements - so I have two main functions `create_transaction()` and `update_node()` to handle those situations respectively.

I'm having two different issues revolving around these functions though. Issue #2 could be dependent on issue #1 though.

1. In my `create_transaction()` I have an inner-function called `init_transaction()` where I am creating the raw HTML code for the "new_transaction" element. Then, I am either appending the element to a new ordered-list (created in `update_node()`) OR  replacing with the original element (utilizing insertBefore() and removing the original_transaction). If I do the insertBefore() condition, I am trying to return a promise to ensure those actions have been performed first before I continue with the rest of the `create_transaction()`. Right now, it seems the call-stack runs everything synchronously still; therefor, my latter JS conditions do not get applied to my new_transaction element because it has not been inserted yet.
2. In my `update_node()`, I am creating a new ordered-list from scratch. Then  I need to append new_transactions to that list (see my very last if/else statement in `update_node()`). So again, I want to make sure I create the ordered-list first and append it to the DOM before I go into my for loop and `create_transaction()`. It seems my ordered-list is not on the DOM yet when my transactions are ready to be append()?

Side note: I'm also trying to understand when to use `.then()` and `.done()` for promises.

Here is some pseudo code.

```
function create_transaction(
    data,
    node_ordinal,
    status,
    original_modal,
    original_transaction = null,
) {

    function init_transaction(data, original_modal, original_transaction) {

        var new_transaction = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        var new_modal = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        $(original_modal)
            .modal("hide")
            .promise()
            .then(function () {
                $(original_modal).remove()
            })

        $(".modal:last").after(new_modal)

        if (!original_transaction) {
            return $(new_transaction)
                .hide()
                .append(
                    $(
                        "#node" +
                            node_ordinal +
                            "-transactions .transaction-section." +
                            status,
                    ),
                )
                .promise()
        } else {
            return $(original_transaction).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(new_transaction)
                    .hide()
                    .insertBefore(original_transaction)
                    .promise()
                    .then(function () {
                        $(original_transaction).remove()
                    })
            })
        }
    }

    init_transaction(data, original_modal, original_transaction).then(
        function () {
            [..lots of JS conditionals to build out each new_tranaction..]
        },
    )
}

function update_node(
  data, 
  original_modal, 
  original_node,
) {

    var new_node = `
        [..creating new raw HTML element..]
    `

    $(original_modal)
        .modal("hide")
        .promise()
        .then(function () {
            $(original_modal).remove()
        })

    $(original_node).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(new_node)
            .hide()
            .insertBefore(original_node)
            .promise()
            .done(function () {
                $(original_node).remove()

                
                [...more JS..]

                for (let i = 0; i < data["node"]["transactions"].length; i++) {
                    if (data["node"]["transactions"][i][0] == "Current") {
                       
                       [...do some stuff..]
                        
                    } else {
                        var transaction_section = `
                            [..this is my ordered-list in raw HTML..]
                        `

                        $(node)
                            .find(".accordion-body")
                            .append(transaction_section)
                            .promise()
                            .then(function () {
                                for (
                                    let x = 0;
                                    x <
                                    data["node"]["transactions"][i][1].length;
                                    x++
                                ) {
                                    create_transaction(
                                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][1][x],
                                        data["node"]["ordinal"],
                                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][0],
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                    }
                }

                $(node).fadeIn("slow")
            })
    })
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I resolved my issue #1 where I am creating a transaction and replacing it with the original_transaction. I did this by returning `new Promise()`. All my JS code in the `.then()` is now being applied to my element before my new transaction appears on the page. Below is my latest code block.

To be consistent, I made some changes to `update_node()`:

- I added an inner-function `init_node()` where I am creating the raw HTML code for the "new_node" element (just like I did in `create_transaction()`). I don't think this was necessary as my "new_node" was not have an issue at this point, but I like it symmetry.

When I start creating all my "new_transaction" elements in the for loop, they are still not getting appended() because I think the "new_node" element has not been placed on the DOM yet.

```
function create_transaction(
    data,
    node_ordinal,
    status,
    original_modal = null,
    original_transaction = null,
) {

    function init_transaction(data, original_modal, original_transaction) {

        var new_transaction = `
           [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        var new_modal = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (!original_transaction) {
                
                [..append new_transaction to new ordered-list..]

                resolve()
            } else {
                $(original_modal)
                    .modal("hide")
                    .promise()
                    .then(function () {
                        $(original_modal).remove()
                    })

                $(".modal:last").after(new_modal)

                $(original_transaction).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(new_transaction)
                        .hide()
                        .insertBefore(original_transaction)
                        .fadeIn("slow")

                    $(original_transaction).remove()

                    resolve()
                })
            }
        })
    }

    init_transaction(data, original_modal, original_transaction).then(
        function () {
            [..lots of JS conditionals to finish each new_tranaction..]
        },
    )
}

function update_node(data, original_modal, original_node) {

    function init_node(data, original_modal, original_node) {
        var new_node = `
        [..creating new raw HTML element..]
    `

        $(original_modal)
            .modal("hide")
            .promise()
            .then(function () {
                $(original_modal).remove()
            })

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $(original_node).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(new_node).hide().insertBefore(original_node).fadeIn("slow")

                $(original_node).remove()
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }

    init_node(data, original_modal, original_node).then(function () {
        
            [..lots of JS conditionals to finish new_node..]

            if (data["node"]["transactions"][i][0] == "Current") {
                
                 [..do some stuff..]

            } else {

                [..HERE IS WHERE I AM CREATING MY NEW ORDERD-LIST..]

                var transaction_section = `
                        <h6>
                            ${data["node"]["transactions"][i][0]}
                        </h6>
                        <ol 
                            class="list-group list-group-numbered mb-3 transaction-section ${data["node"]["transactions"][i][0]}"
                        >
                        </ol>
                    `

                $(node).find(".accordion-body").append(transaction_section)

                for (
                    let x = 0;
                    x < data["node"]["transactions"][i][1].length;
                    x++
                ) {
                    create_transaction(
                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][1][x],
                        data["node"]["ordinal"],
                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][0],
                    )
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After much hair-pulling, I realized my `create_transaction()` was using the append method incorrectly. I was trying to append my Jquery selector instead of my "new_transaction" `$(selector).append([..my new transaction..])`

This resolved all my problems once I noticed this error. I also made some small changes when I hide and remove my original modal so it is more useful. Here is my updated code (including the event listeners so you can get the entire picture) for anyone following this question. Thanks.

```
function create_transaction(
    data,
    node_ordinal,
    status,
    original_transaction = null,
) {


    var original_modals = $(".transaction" + data["id"].$oid + "-modal")

    $(original_modals).remove()

    function init_transaction(data, original_transaction) {
        var new_transaction = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        for (let i = 0; i < data["menu"].length; i++) {
            if (data["menu"][i][1] == "update") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            } else if (data["menu"][i][1] == "delete") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            } else if (data["menu"][i][1] == "rectify") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            } else if (data["menu"][i][1] == "rectify-undo") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            }

            $(".modal:last").after(new_modal)
        }

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (!original_transaction) {

                [..THIS WAS WERE MY ERROR WAS..]
                $(
                    "#node" +
                        node_ordinal +
                        "-transactions .transaction-section." +
                        status,
                ).append(new_transaction)

                resolve()
            } else {
                $(original_transaction).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(new_transaction)
                        .hide()
                        .insertBefore(original_transaction)
                        .fadeIn("slow")

                    $(original_transaction).remove()

                    resolve()
                })
            }
        })
    }

    init_transaction(data, original_transaction).then(function () {
        

        [..lots of JS conditionals to build out each new_transaction and new_modal created..]

    })
}

function update_node(data, original_node) {
    
    function init_node(data, original_node) {
        var new_node = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $(original_node).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(new_node).hide().insertBefore(original_node).fadeIn("slow")

                $(original_node).remove()
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }

    init_node(data, original_node).then(function () {

        for (let i = 0; i < data["node"]["transactions"].length; i++) {
            if (data["node"]["transactions"][i][0] == "Current") {
                
                 [..lots of JS conditionals to build out new_node..]

            } else {
                var transaction_section = `
                    [..this is my ordered-list in raw HTML..]
                `

                $(node).find(".accordion-body").append(transaction_section)

                for (
                    let x = 0;
                    x < data["node"]["transactions"][i][1].length;
                    x++
                ) {
                    create_transaction(
                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][1][x],
                        data["node"]["ordinal"],
                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][0],
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

$(document).on("submit", "form.update-transaction", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    var form = this
    var modal = $(this).closest(".modal")
    var url = $(form).attr("action")
    var method = $(form).attr("method")
    var transactionObjectId = $(form)
        .find('input[name="transactionObjectId"]')
        .val()

    var original_transaction = $("li.transaction").filter(function (i, item) {
        return transactionObjectId == $(item).data("transaction-object-id")
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: [..form data..],
        success: function (data) {
            $(modal).modal("hide")

            create_transaction(data, null, null, original_transaction)
        },
    })
})

$(document).on("submit", "form.update-circuit", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    var form = this
    var modal = $(this).closest(".modal")
    var url = $(form).attr("action")
    var method = $(form).attr("method")
    var transactionObjectId = $(form)
        .find('input[name="transactionObjectId"]')
        .val()

    var original_transaction = $("li.transaction").filter(function (i, item) {
        return transactionObjectId == $(item).data("transaction-object-id")
    })

    var original_node = $(original_transaction).closest(".node")

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: [..form data..],
        success: function (data) {
            $(modal).modal("hide")

            update_node(data, original_node)
        },
    })
})
```

Comment: "*I want to make sure I delete the original_transaction before I move on to the rest of the code, so I am trying to return a promise to ensure those actions have been performed first*" - that's pointless. DOM manipulation is synchronous, there is no need to use promises here, everything already happens in the order that you write in the code. Just write standard, boring, synchronous code.

Comment: (The only exception to that would be if "deleting the element" entails animating its removal, and you want to wait for the asynchronous animation - then a promise chain would be appropriate)

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm doing something wrong on appending my code to the DOM because after I append "new_transaction", I have to manipulate it and those changes are not getting captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my **UPDATE 2** here as the answer.

After much hair-pulling, I realized my `create_transaction()` was using the append method incorrectly. I was trying to append my Jquery selector instead of my "new_transaction" `$(selector).append([..my new transaction..])`

This resolved all my problems once I noticed this error. I also made some small changes when I hide and remove my original modal so it is more useful. Here is my updated code (including the event listeners so you can get the entire picture) for anyone following this question. Thanks.

```
function create_transaction(
    data,
    node_ordinal,
    status,
    original_transaction = null,
) {


    var original_modals = $(".transaction" + data["id"].$oid + "-modal")

    $(original_modals).remove()

    function init_transaction(data, original_transaction) {
        var new_transaction = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        for (let i = 0; i < data["menu"].length; i++) {
            if (data["menu"][i][1] == "update") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            } else if (data["menu"][i][1] == "delete") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            } else if (data["menu"][i][1] == "rectify") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            } else if (data["menu"][i][1] == "rectify-undo") {
                var new_modal = `
                    [..creating new raw HTML element..]
                `
            }

            $(".modal:last").after(new_modal)
        }

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (!original_transaction) {

                [..THIS WAS WERE MY ERROR WAS..]
                $(
                    "#node" +
                        node_ordinal +
                        "-transactions .transaction-section." +
                        status,
                ).append(new_transaction)

                resolve()
            } else {
                $(original_transaction).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(new_transaction)
                        .hide()
                        .insertBefore(original_transaction)
                        .fadeIn("slow")

                    $(original_transaction).remove()

                    resolve()
                })
            }
        })
    }

    init_transaction(data, original_transaction).then(function () {
        

        [..lots of JS conditionals to build out each new_transaction and new_modal created..]

    })
}

function update_node(data, original_node) {
    
    function init_node(data, original_node) {
        var new_node = `
            [..creating new raw HTML element..]
        `

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $(original_node).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(new_node).hide().insertBefore(original_node).fadeIn("slow")

                $(original_node).remove()
                resolve()
            })
        })
    }

    init_node(data, original_node).then(function () {

        for (let i = 0; i < data["node"]["transactions"].length; i++) {
            if (data["node"]["transactions"][i][0] == "Current") {
                
                 [..lots of JS conditionals to build out new_node..]

            } else {
                var transaction_section = `
                    [..this is my ordered-list in raw HTML..]
                `

                $(node).find(".accordion-body").append(transaction_section)

                for (
                    let x = 0;
                    x < data["node"]["transactions"][i][1].length;
                    x++
                ) {
                    create_transaction(
                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][1][x],
                        data["node"]["ordinal"],
                        data["node"]["transactions"][i][0],
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

$(document).on("submit", "form.update-transaction", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    var form = this
    var modal = $(this).closest(".modal")
    var url = $(form).attr("action")
    var method = $(form).attr("method")
    var transactionObjectId = $(form)
        .find('input[name="transactionObjectId"]')
        .val()

    var original_transaction = $("li.transaction").filter(function (i, item) {
        return transactionObjectId == $(item).data("transaction-object-id")
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: [..form data..],
        success: function (data) {
            $(modal).modal("hide")

            create_transaction(data, null, null, original_transaction)
        },
    })
})

$(document).on("submit", "form.update-circuit", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    var form = this
    var modal = $(this).closest(".modal")
    var url = $(form).attr("action")
    var method = $(form).attr("method")
    var transactionObjectId = $(form)
        .find('input[name="transactionObjectId"]')
        .val()

    var original_transaction = $("li.transaction").filter(function (i, item) {
        return transactionObjectId == $(item).data("transaction-object-id")
    })

    var original_node = $(original_transaction).closest(".node")

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: [..form data..],
        success: function (data) {
            $(modal).modal("hide")

            update_node(data, original_node)
        },
    })
})
```